# Magento1.9 return to listing Invalid entity type

Tags: php, grid, magento-1.9

After save the product while return to listing grid sometimes we are facing below **“Invalid entity type”** error. We had added a custom column to the grid name as Old SKU. I don’t know why this error occurred. Anyone please let me know how to fix this issue.

> Error

```
   a:5:{i:0;s:19:"Invalid entity type";i:1;s:4744:"#0 app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(639): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Invalid entity ...')
    #1 app/code/local/Narayan/Catalogextended/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Grid.php(31): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->joinAttribute('old_sku', '', 'entity_id', NULL, 'left', '1')
    #2 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php(123): Narayan_Catalogextended_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid->setCollection(Object(OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection))
    #3 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(626): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid->_prepareCollection()
    #4 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
    #5 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(922): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
    #6 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #7 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
    #8 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product.php(79): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
    #9 app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product.phtml(46): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product->getGridHtml()
    #10 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/abc/...')
    #11 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
    #12 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
    #13 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
    #14 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
    #15 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
    #16 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #17 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
    #18 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #19 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
    #20 app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
    #21 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/abc/...')
    #22 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
    #23 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
    #24 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
    #25 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
    #26 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #27 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
    #28 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(180): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
    #29 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->indexAction()
    #30 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
    #31 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #32 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #33 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #34 index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #35 {main}";s:3:"url";s:91:"/index.php/admin/catalog_product/index/store/1/key/2e0cc3856e92a5219433d7f0996c7c48/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Comment: How did you create custom field "old_sku" in products, ?

Comment: @Ajith I have created a local module and extend the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid` there

Comment: Can you check if backend_type value get entered into eav_attribute table ?

Comment: @Ajith no value exist in eav_attribute table regarding custom_culumn

Comment: Can you make a full database search for your custom variable "old_sku", It will be available in one of the *__attribute table , If you found that please check its datatype

Comment: @Ajith its found in same table with backend type `varchar`

Comment: Which table you find the result?

Comment: @Ajith in `eav_attribute` table. previously I was searching in wrong column :)

Comment: Please check if association exists in *_entity_varchar tables  Please refer this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-7.html

Comment: @Ajith yes entry exist in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table for all the products